# What is the calculation ratio?

Tags: php, logic

I have the following rule:

If you buy 2 products get 3 free:

- if buy 1 get 0
- if buy 2 get 3
- if buy 3 get 3
- if buy 4 get 6
- if buy 5 get 6
- if buy 6 get 9
- if buy 7 get 9
- if buy 8 get 12
- if buy 9 get 12
- if buy 10 get 15
  .....

If you buy 3 products get 2 free:

- if buy 1 get 0
- if buy 2 get 0
- if buy 3 get 2
- if buy 4 get 2
- if buy 5 get 2
- if buy 6 get 4
- if buy 7 get 4
- if buy 8 get 4
- if buy 9 get 6
- if buy 10 get 6
  ...

I need the formula the calculate this.

For "If you buy 2 products get 3 free:" CASE:

(quantity/ratio)*free_items
if buy 10 get 15 = `(10/2)*3 = 5*3 = 15` - which is correct

BUT:
if buy 3 get 3 = `(3/2)*3 = 1.5*3 = 4.5` - which is NOT correct

Is there someone who can help me with this.

Comment: You have 2 rules, so you should use separate formula for each.

Comment: I don't know what language you are using, but after you divide the total bought by the break point, you need to get the floor value of it before you multiply by the reward.  In C#, you can cast it to an int.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert to integer the result of the division:

```
youGet = intval( quantity/ratio ) * freeItems
```

I used the [`intval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function that will return the integer part of the division.

Answer (score 0):

divide by how many products need to buy, round downwards to zero and multiply by amount of free products.

if you buy `$howmanybuy` products get `$howmanyfree` free:

```
$get = floor($quantity / $howmanybuy) * $howmanyfree;
```